# Angular 5 dynamic created component interaction

Tags: angular

What i'm trying to achieve:

first component creates and sends "Project" instance to server, after that i need to tell another component (which contains Project tree of existing projects) to update tree.
I've tried to do this with help of EventEmitter, but nothing happens.
Apparently this doesn't work if an emitter component created dynamically.

What are options to solve this?

Dynamically created component:

```
export class AddProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  newProject: Project;
  newProjectData: NewProjectDataResponse;

  @Output() onProjectAdd = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newProjectData = new NewProjectDataResponse();
    this.newProject = new Project();
    this.projectService.getNewProjectData()
      .subscribe(
        result => this.newProjectData = result,
        error => this.newProjectData.error = 'Error!'
      );
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.projectService.addNewProject(this.newProject);
    this.onProjectAdd.emit();
  }
```

and the parent component:

```
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  component: Type<any>;
  injector: Injector;

  private showWp: boolean;

  constructor(private inj: Injector) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showWp = false;
  }

  loadProjectDetails(basicProj: BasicProject): void {

    this.component = ProjectComponent;
    this.injector = Injector.create([{provide: BasicProject, useValue: basicProj}], this.inj);
  }

  updateProjectsTree() {
    console.info('Update tree');
  }
}
```

the template of the parent comp.:

```
<div class="basicContainer">
  <div class="projectsTreeContainer">


    <input type="text" id="searchWord" placeholder="Search through projects"/>

    <button (click)="loadAddProject()">Add new Project</button>

    <app-projects-tree (onLoadProjectDetails)="loadProjectDetails($event)"
                       (onLoadWpDetails)="loadWpDetails($event)"
                       (onSelectAndLoadJobDetails)="loadJobDetails($event)">

    </app-projects-tree>
  </div>

  <div class="infoContainer">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component; injector: injector" (onProjectAdd)="updateProjectsTree($event)"></ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution - to use a dedicated service. The service looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class TreeUpdateService {

  private update = new Subject();
  updateObservable = this.update.asObservable();

  upd() {
    this.update.next();
  }
}
```

dynamically created comp. after service implementation:

```
export class AddProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  newProject: Project;
  newProjectData: NewProjectDataResponse;

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectsService, private updateTreeService: TreeUpdateService) {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.projectService.addNewProject(this.newProject).subscribe(
      response => {
        alert('Project has been saved successfully');
        this.updateTreeService.upd();
      },
      error => {
        if (error.status === 406) {
          alert('Project with name: ' + this.newProject.name + ' exists already.');
        } else {
          alert('Unknown error has occur.');
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

And the component to be updated:

```
export class ProjectsTreeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private projectsService: ProjectsService, private updateTreeService: TreeUpdateService) {
    this.updateTreeService.updateObservable.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.updateProjectsTree();
      }
    );
  }
```